# how to set the multiple short footnote in a line

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs

How to get these automation

"if a Short single notes in a page should be centred. 
Set several very short notes on same line
with 3 EMs # between"

like the below output

```
1. Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text

2. short footnote    3. short footnote 4.    shortfootnote

5. Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text Sample Footnote text
```

Comment: i have tried with bigfoot package, but i cant use the vertical meterials like, enumerate, quote, equation etc, it is showing error, hyperlink also is not working

Comment: May be is useful for you `\usepackage{fnpara}`in the preamble, although this package put **all** footnotes in a run-on para­graphs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`bigfoot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package features (besides the improved standard macro `\footnote`) the macros `\footnote+` which forces plain footnotes (even when the default style is `para`) and `\footnote-` which forces paragraph-style footnotes (even when the default is `plain`). Footnotes which include displayed equations, quotes or list environments must be in plain style; therefore, if your default style is `para`, you must use `\footnote+` for the respective notes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

First paragraph.\footnote+{%
\sometext

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
}

Second paragraph.\footnote{A short footnote.}

Third paragraph.\footnote{Another short footnote.}

Fourth paragraph.\footnote+{%
\sometext

\begin{quote}
\sometext
\end{quote}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer this over the [para] option of footmisc because it keeps overflowing footnotes on their own lines, making them look somewhat clean. footmisc will just treat everything as a single blob of text and add everything to the previous line if it fits anyway